# js regex to extract a string from a string containing asterisks

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
**********3600 - $20.00
```

I need to extract just `3600` from it. I can't search specifically for 3600, as the string is dynamic, and I can't do an extraction based on position, as there may be a different number of asterisks at the beginning of the string. So I need a regex that will extract the four characters immediately after the last asterisk, but I'm really not that great with regex, and since the asterisk is a reserved character in regex, I don't know how to escape it. Can anyone help?

Comment: any four chars, or always digits?

Comment: It will always be digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the matches will be the first number, you could actually just do:

```
string.match(/\d+/);
```

it will match the first number. Since you don't add the global flag, it only gets the first match.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
str.match(/^\**(\d+)/)
```

The result, if any, will be in the index 1 of the returned array. You may want to check whether the returned result is `null` or not before proceed to get the number.

#### Assumption

Note that this solution assumes that the string *starts with* an arbitrary number of `*` (I allow the case where digits start right at the beginning), followed by a sequence of digits (at least one digit) that you want to extract.

#### Explanation

```
/^\**(\d+)/
```

- `/` at the beginning and the end are delimiters for JavaScript literal `RegExp`.
- `^` matches start of the string
- `\*` matches literal `*`, since `*` has special meaning in regex. The `*` followed right after make it matches 0 or more instances of asterisk `*`.
- `(\d+)`: `\d` matches a digit (from 0 to 9), `+` means repeated once or more. The `()` makes a *capturing group*, so that we can extract the content matched by this regex (as you can see above, when you refer to index 1 of the returned array for the number).

Answer (score 0):

any four chars, or always digits?

```
/^\**(\d{4})/   if it's just digits
/^\**(.{4})/    for any 4 random characters.
  ^---escape char
```

Note the backslash as escape char.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how this works. I tried it in a <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/StLLV/">fiddle</a>, and it returns an array containing both the complete string and the extracted string. How can I return only the extracted string?

Comment: that's normal behavior. when capturing you always get the entire string that the match(es) came from as the first element in the array, and then the individual captures.